# Generic class compiles in Java 6, but not Java 7

Tags: java, generics, collections, java-7, java-6

I have an interface in Java 6 that compiles correctly:

```
public interface IMultiMap<K, V> extends Map<K, Set<V>> {

    public int valueSize();

    public boolean put(K key, V value);

    public void clear(Object key);

    public boolean isEmpty(Object key);
}
```

But in Java 7, this interface doesn't compile. I get a compile error on `boolean put(K, V)` that it has the same erasure as `V put(K, V)`. The full error from the compiler:

```
error: name clash: put(K#1,V#1) in IMultiMap and put(K#2,V#2) in Map have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
    public boolean put(K key, V value);
  where K#1,V#1,K#2,V#2 are type-variables:
    K#1 extends Object declared in interface IMultiMap
    V#1 extends Object declared in interface IMultiMap
    K#2 extends Object declared in interface Map
    V#2 extends Object declared in interface Map
```

For the record, adding any kind of overriding doesn't work. I tried explicitly overriding `Map.put`, but the error still comes up. Changing the return type of my `put` is moot since this error is blocking that potential error from ever being reached, and if this error were fixed, then the two methods wouldn't have the same name/parameter signature anyway.

I think I might try some reflection on Java 6 and see what the actual parameter types end up being in Java 6's compiled bytecode. It's clear that both Java 7 methods are being erased to `put(Object, Object)`. I'll post the reflection results here once I do that.

In the meantime, my temporary workaround will be just to rename `put` to `putSingle`, but is this new behavior correct? Did some part of the generics specifications change for Java 7 that makes the old Java 6 behavior wrong? Or is this a bug in the Java 7 compiler?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I ran the reflection code. Check out my answer below.

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using? It works for me.

Comment: Scratch that. This works with Eclipse's compiler but not JDK 7u6.

Comment: 1.7.0_03. I'll try updating. **EDIT:** That's an interesting distinction.

Comment: Doesn't compile with 1.7.0_06. What version of 1.6 were you using?

Comment: Our target is JDK 6u17 for 6.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it's a bug in 1.6 that was fixed in 1.7. Extract from [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#jdk7):

> **Synopsis:** A Class Cannot Define Two Methods with the Same Erased Signature but Two Different Return Types
>   **Description:** A class cannot define two methods with the same erased signature, regardless of whether the return types are the same or not. This follows from the JLS, Java SE 7 Edition, section 8.4.8.3. The JDK 6 compiler allows methods with the same erased signature but different return types; this behavior is incorrect and has been fixed in JDK 7.
>   **Example:**

```
class A {
   int m(List<String> ls) { return 0; }
   long m(List<Integer> ls) { return 1; }
}
```

> This code compiles under JDK 5.0 and JDK 6, and is rejected under JDK 7.

Comment: @Brian well it was not really a bug of javac; the language spec failed to account for some corner cases introduced by the wonderful "erasure"

Answer (score 1):

I ran the reflection code on Java 6.

Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class<IMultiMap> immClass = IMultiMap.class;
    Method[] methods = immClass.getMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (method.getName().equals("put"))
            System.out.println(method.toString());
    }
}
```

Here are the method signatures for the class:

```
public abstract boolean IMultiMap.put(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)
public abstract java.lang.Object java.util.Map.put(java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)
```

Or more concisely:

```
boolean put(Object, Object)
Object  put(Object, Object)
```

So they are erased to the same parameters with a different return type. I guess it's <strike>a bug</strike> an unspecified edge case in the Java 6 JLS then, as per assylias' answer. I wonder how Java 6 managed to resolve these methods correctly on runtime?

**Edit:** According to x4u's comment, the calling bytecode maintains a reference to the *entire* signature when it's compiled, so that's why the correct method was being called by the JVM. Since the compiler was probably capable of telling which method I was calling due to its access to the source (and thus to the generics information), the compiler probably linked it to the correct method via the entire signature. Interesting to know!

Comment: At Bytecode level methods are always referenced with their full signature which includes the return type. Thus a class can have any number of methods with the same name and argument list but different return types and you can still invoke either of them. Bytecode obfuscators have been relying on this for years. It's always been the job of the compiler to ensure that you can't create such classes directly. Also the compiler needs to create bridge methods if you override a super method with one with a more specific return type and thus it creates 2 methods that only differ in return type.