# Java generics name clash after type erasure

Tags: java, generics

I am working through "Java Generics and Collections" book, and came across this piece of code, which is supposed to compile and run without errors

```
class Overloaded {
    public static Integer sum(List<Integer> ints) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i : ints) sum += i;
        return sum;
    }
    public static String sum(List<String> strings) {
        StringBuffer sum = new StringBuffer();
        for (String s : strings) sum.append(s);
        return sum.toString();
    }
}
```

However, this example fails to compile with error

> Error:(16, 26) java: name clash: sum(java.util.List)
>   and sum(java.util.List) have the same erasure

I can understand why this is an error. However, the book specifically mentions that this is allowed, as compiler can distinguish the 2 methods based on return type.

I then found this thread
[Type Erasure and Overloading in Java: Why does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527235/type-erasure-and-overloading-in-java-why-does-this-work)

It also suggests that this example should compile. Any idea what's causing the compile to fail?

I am using JDK 1.8. Is this recently changed with Java 1.8? In case this is relevant, I am using latest IntelliJ IDEA as IDE.

Comment: Can you check what JDK version IntelliJ has been configured to compile this code?

Comment: The post quoted refers to a bug of javac compilation  java 6. You use java 8.

Comment: @davidxxx - that is not very clear. Is it not working in Java8 or Java6?

Comment: You normally can't overload based on return type alone, that other example you linked doesn't compile for me either.

Comment: @Minh Kieu You are right. Not super clear and some answers are also contradictory. The duplicate referenced by chengpohi is much cleared.

Comment: @MinhKieu Edited to include that I am using JDK 1.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As we know, In the **Runtime**, **Java** will **erasure generic type**, so:

```
Integer sum(List<Integer> ints)
String sum(List<String> strings)
```

will be translated to in **Runtime**:

```
Integer sum(List ints)
String sum(List strings)
```

so this **compiler error** should be throwed.

It compiles without throwing error in **JDK6** it's a bug. this bug has been fixed in **JDK7**, so compile with **JDK8** will throw this compile error.

Reference:

[Generic class compiles in Java 6, but not Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206181/generic-class-compiles-in-java-6-but-not-java-7)

Comment: Actually, the type information is still there at runtime, you can even get it with reflection: `ParameterizedType pType = (ParameterizedType) Overloaded.class.getMethod("sum", List.class).getGenericParameterTypes()[0];` It's just that, if you were to call `sum` with a raw `List`, the compiler wouldn't know which method to bind. The caller would be forced to use generics to make the call not ambiguous, but that defeats the point of using a raw type.